# Two identical Strings that don't equal each other

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm having trouble comparing two strings that should really be the same but when I evaluate it in alert(f==g) it evaluates to false.

```
var oTrackCarriers = {
"9045": [
["A"],
["B"],
["C"]
],
"9046": [
[" "] 
]
};
var oHeadingCarriers = {
"Ripplefold": [
["A"],
["B"],
["C"],
["D"]
],
"PinchPleat": [
["C"],
["D"]
]
};
var HeadingList = oHeadingCarriers["Ripplefold"];
var TrackList = oTrackCarriers["9045"]
var f = (TrackList[0].valueOf());
var g = (HeadingList[0].valueOf());
alert(f);
alert(g);
alert(f == g);
```

Is this because I'm putting the two values into an array beforehand?

Here's it running  http://jsfiddle.net/sQrST/17/embedded/result/
thanks for the help

Comment: This is why you need to be testing using console.log and not alert.

Comment: You are comparing arrays, not strings. `oHeadingCarriers["Ripplefold"][0]` is an array, as is `oTrackCarriers["9045"][0]`. If you compare the first element of each of *those* arrays, *then* you'd see equality.

Comment: @apsillers is right. Why do you have brackets around your final values (`A, B, C`)?

Comment: What's the `.valueOf()` supposed to do? It will yield the array it was called on, not a primitive value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`["A"]` is an array. You can either get the string value with `TrackList[0][0]` and `HeadingList[0][0]` or check if every string contained in `TrackList[0]` and `HeadingList[0]` are equals. Usually, two arrays are always differents when comparing them directly. In fact, an array is equal to another if their memory addresses are the same, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
var oTrackCarriers = { "9045": [["A"], ["B"], ["C"]],
                       "9046": [[" "]] };

var TrackList = oTrackCarriers["9045"];   // TrackList = [["A"], ["B"], ["C"]]

var f = (TrackList[0].valueOf())          // f =  ["A"]
```

`alert()` displays arrays in a non intuitive way, so the fact that f (and g) are arrays is hidden, and comparisons of arrays don't do an element wise comparison of the elements, it compares if the variables reference the *same* array;

```
["A"] == ["A"] 
> false

"A" == "A"
> true

a = ['A']
b = a
a == b
> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont compare the arrays ... change to this:

```
alert(f[0]);
alert(g[0]);
alert(f[0] == g[0]);
```

and now its 'true'